# A word for discrimination based on education or area of expertise

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I was wondering if there is a word for "discrimination on the basis of education / area of expertise".

What I mean is a word to describe someones attitude toward geeks of some kind.

Example:
I want to find a word that ungrounded feeling of inherent intellectual superiority toward a group of people with different education, e.g mathematicians towards physicists and vice versa.

Comment: Now that i re-read it, it doesn't seem like a great title.

Comment: If there can be postcodist thinking, there's always a possibility to cast a word for this.

Comment: @Kris: That's a big if.

Comment: @Kris: I'm quite familiar with the *concept* (which is more often evoked by the set phrase "postcode lottery"), but it took me a while to work out what you meant by *postcodist thinking*. Interestingly, Google reports 45 results for ***postcodism***, but only 2 for ***zipcodism***. Which presumably just goes to show the Brits are still a class-ridden society, by comparison with the US.

Comment: @Cynic: Are we to assume you're asking about a word for the way some people (esp. artistically-inclined and/or stupid people) disparage scientists/engineers/geeks? Your title suggests you might be asking about the more general distrust felt towards people educated at Eton/Oxbridge (more a UK than a US attitude, I think, since Americans don't habitually slag off "the Harvard set" or similar).

Comment: @TimLymington I s'pose FF has answered the 'if' part adequately.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was only referring to the *concept* and not its geographical/ cultural implications at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not localized to education, but a term that might work is [*collective/group narcissism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_narcissism), which WP says to be

> a type of narcissism where an individual has an inflated self-love of his or her own ingroup

The terms [*collective narcissism*](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22collective+narcissism%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C32) and [*group narcissism*](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22group+narcissism%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C32) appear to be equal in popularity, yielding about 500 hits each in Google Scholar. But these searches and an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=group+narcissism%2Ccollective+narcissism&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cgroup%20narcissism%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgroup%20narcissism%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGroup%20narcissism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccollective%20narcissism%3B%2Cc0) search suggest *collective narcissism* is used slightly more.

Correct usage depends on the circumstances. For example, enmity between a group and only one other is not necessarily an instance of an ["*inflated* view of one's ingroup"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_narcissism#Characteristics) -- it may simply be disdain for someone else's -- but a new member adopting this enmity in order to feel part of the group arguably can be.

**Note on first edit**: My first edit mistakenly answered *What is an antonym of "geek"?* But, due to a sloppily written last sentence, it sounded like I was saying "people who use *muggle* to describe non-enthusiasts are geeks." My apologies to anyone who might have taken it this way; it was not my intention.

Comment: Surprised this was accepted, this really isn't an answer with enough specificity....No offense to OP, it's a good try, but seems a swing and a miss to me...

Answer (score 1):

I have always used the phrase intellectual elitism.

Answer (score 0):

It would be *differentiation* on the basis of expertise or specialization, not *discrimination*.  I feel you want to use *prejudiced*.

Comment: Some citations would improve this answer, not least by reassuring us that you yourself know the relevant definitions.

Comment: What @Tim said. But I'm not even convinced that justifies *downvoting* the answer, let alone flagging it as "low quality - needs attention from the mods".

Comment: Can I know exactly why I'm not eligible to give answers anymore,I seriously think she wanted to mean prejudiced.i don't give answers if I don't think it's conclusive,atleast from now on I solemnly say I won't .

Comment: @Anshu: I don't know why you can't give answers anymore. You could [ask on meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/), but my guess is it might be because the two downvotes reduced your "reputation" and that restricted your "privileges". Note the upvotes for Tim's comment - if you were to ***edit*** this answer to include links and/or definitions for the three highlighted words, those downvotes might be retracted/reversed (they probably wouldn't have been cast in the first place if you'd done this when you originally posted the answer).

Answer (score -1):

I usually use morphosism (my neologism) which is based on the Greek Morphosis (means education or used for well educated person). I am a psychologist and I find morphosism to be the basis of so much elitism and discrimination on the island of Cyprus where I live and at the University where I teach.

Comment: -1. Marios, I doubt anyone would understand you if you said you were subjected to morphosism - in fact, I suspect most would assume it's some kind of disease. You might like to read our site guidance, especially [answer] and [Tour].