# What is it called when one believes to be superior but objectively is not?

Tags: verbs, idioms

On a television documentary, a small group of people declared **and truly believed** themselves to be superior to other groups.

They referred to themselves as "thoroughbreds" citing physical, mental *and* behavioral superiority.

Objectively speaking, it's clear that it is false - that other groups can outperform them in all those aspects. (or at least for this question, lets say they would **not** end up scoring first place on objective tests for those attributes).

What is this phenomenon called ?

(Please note, this question has nothing to do with any single group. This concept is actually seen across many different groups, which in itself, is a complete paradox).

Comment: [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145285) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49949) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469491) and [others](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=group+superior)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Delusional.** Otherwise, a term like **superiority complex** seems most appropriate.

Comment: ok, I was thinking that too but didn't know if it was too general, as someone who sees Unicorns is also delusional. This one is fixed relative to other people...maybe all of them together -  a delusional superiority complex?